# flutter build appbundle "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm attempting to get my first Flutter app to the PlayStore.  I am following the instructions here for Android:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

When I get to the instructions on building an appbundle, I encounter an error:

```
flutter build appbundle
Running "flutter pub get" in weight_list...                         4.9s

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...      

                  

















FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/michaelalbrecht/StudioProjects/weight_list/android/app/build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: java.util.Properties.exists() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: list(java.io.PrintStream), list(java.io.PrintWriter), wait(), equals(java.lang.Object), wait(long), equals(java.lang.Object)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              5.9s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

It says the problem is on line 29 in build.gradle.  Line 29 for me is the third line of the following, which is what the documentation told me to add:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystoreProperties.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

I'm thinking something is wrong in the key.properties file (which is supposed to be kept private, so I can't share with you).  But I followed the instructions in the documentation, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `.exists()` on `keyStoreProperties`, instead of `keyStorePropertiesFile`. Change line 29 like this:

```
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes.  Thanks.